# How to programmatically dismiss the keyboard in Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

There are numerous examples of how to do this in native Objective-C but I can't seem to find an example of how to accomplish the same in C# code in MonoTouch.

I would like to dismiss the Keyboard that pops up when user presses the return key.

Is EditingDidEnd the right event to trap? I can't seem to find the dismiss first responder method call.

Help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look [here](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Elements.cs#L1582) for a sample.

In general it's much easier if you can link to samples. People will see exactly what you want and tell you how to do so using MonoTouch. Also providing your own, partial/unworking code, is often a big help.

Answer (score 3):

[Here is gist showing](https://gist.github.com/3844649) how to add closing button above numeric keyboard. You can do this with 1LOC

```
myTextField.SetKeyboardEditorWithCloseButton(UIKeyboardType.NumberPad);
```

using this extension method:

```
public static void SetKeyboardEditorWithCloseButton (this UITextField txt, UIKeyboardType     keyboardType, string closeButtonText = "Done")
{
    UIToolbar toolbar = new UIToolbar ();
    txt.KeyboardType = keyboardType;
    toolbar.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Black;
    toolbar.Translucent = true;
    toolbar.SizeToFit ();
    UIBarButtonItem doneButton = new UIBarButtonItem (closeButtonText, UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done,
                                                      (s, e) => {
        txt.ResignFirstResponder ();
    });
    toolbar.SetItems (new UIBarButtonItem[]{doneButton}, true);

    txt.InputAccessoryView = toolbar;
}
```

[numeric keyboard with closing button http://moocode.net/img/numeric_editor.png](http://moocode.net/img/numeric_editor.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your `TouchesBegan()` method, just call `textbox.ResignFirstReponder()` for any textbox like you normally would or `View.EndEditing(true);`. This is, of course, only if you are somewhere that is inheriting from `UIViewController` and has those events.

Comment: I trapped the DidEndEditing event and called ResignFirstResponder() in the sender. That seems to do the trick.